# Parser that can parse Expression with braces

Tags: java, parsing

hi i have made a simple parser in java which
parses arithmatic expressions like 1+4,-5/3-7...
and my question is how can i modify my cosw
so that it can also parse braces like(-3+6)/7...
my idea is unclear......
any one please give me just ideas so that i can
make it working....
thank you
this is my code

```
package parser;
public class Parser
{
    boolean isNum(StringBuffer s)
    {
        try
        {
            Double.parseDouble(new String(s));
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    double toNum(StringBuffer s)
    {
        return Double.parseDouble(new String(s));
    }
    double eval(StringBuffer exp)
    {        
       if(isNum(exp))
       {
           return toNum(exp);
       }
       else if(!isNum(exp))
       {
           for(int i=exp.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
           {
               if(exp.charAt(i)=='/')
               {               
                   return (double)eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(0, i))) / eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(i+1,exp.length())));
               }
               else if(exp.charAt(i)=='*')
               {
                   return (double)eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(0, i))) * eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(i+1,exp.length())));
               }
               else if(exp.charAt(i)=='-')
               {
                   return (double)eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(0, i))) - eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(i+1,exp.length())));
               }
               else if(exp.charAt(i)=='+')
               {
                   return (double)eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(0, i))) + eval(new StringBuffer(exp.substring(i+1,exp.length())));
               }
           }
       }
       return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Simple Expression Parser \n");
        System.out.println(new Parser().eval(new StringBuffer("-1+2*3/4")));
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry...even if i add code tags it loses its indenting :( .but see my question in dic..it is cleverly formatted http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/342427-simple-parser-that-can-parse-expression-with-braces/

Comment: I have the expression that your parser does not apply precedence rules correctly.

Comment: @LutzHorn It doesn't apply operator precedence rules at all, let alone correctly.

Comment: if my implementation doesn't apply operator precedence tell me how to do it....

Comment: How about you read the material that EJP has suggested and then ask specifically about those parts you have trouble with. It will tell you how to do it.

Comment: maybe i am in a wrong way.i read the articles myself and as i have no much coding experience,i somehow managed to make this dummy parser.i am just interested in it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have made a simple parser in java which parses arithmatic expressions like 1+4,-5/3-7

But not correctly. You haven't implemented operator precedence.

You need to look up the Dijsktra Shunting-yard algorithm, or recursive descent expression parsing. There you will also find how to handle parentheses correctly.

Comment: You have already done what? And you are confused about what? What is your question?

Comment: confused on how to implement

Comment: Is it too much for you to take the trouble to at least write a complete sentence? If you don't ask a proper question you cannot rationally expect a proper answer. These are very well-known algorithms that are explained in numerous readily accessible sources.

Comment: 'Confused on how to implement' is not a sentence, nor a problem description, and it is also incomprehensible to me without more information. There is *source code* for both algorithms available in the Internet in several languages, as well as extremely clear explanations, polished over a long period. Nothing you get here could possibly be as helpful as say the Wikipedia articles. How about showing us some evidence that you've read any of it?

Comment: maybe i am in a wrong way.i read the articles myself and as i have no much coding experience,i somehow managed to make this dummy parser.i am just interested in it..